# Proof of the Erdős–Kaplanski theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, cardinals

> **Theorem (Erdős–Kaplanski)** *Let $F$ be a field, $V$ an infinite-dimensional vector space over $F$. Then $\dim V^*=|V^*|$.*

I have read the proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces) by Pierre-Yves Gaillard, but I can't understand the notation. In particular, what does $$K_1:=K_0(\{b_j\ |\ b\in B,\ j\in\mathbb N\})$$ mean and why $|K_1|<|K|$? I guess $b_j$ means the $j$th coordinate of $b\in K^\mathbb{N}$, and $K_0(X)$ means the subfield generated by $K_0\cup X$. However, I can't see how $|K_1|<|K|$. Can someone explain? I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your interpretation that $b_j$ is the $j$-th coordinate of $b\in B$, as such interpretation seems to work in that proof. I think $|K_1|<|K|$ is apparent, since the prime field $K_0$ has cardinality no larger than $\aleph_0$ and thus $$|K_1|\leqslant|K_0(x_1,\cdots,x_n,\cdots)|=\aleph_0=|B|<|K|,$$
where $x_1,\cdots,x_n\cdots$ are indeterminates over $K_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not familiar with cardinal numbers, so could you please explain why $|K_0(x_1,\cdots,x_n,\cdots)|=\aleph_0$?

Comment: @Colescu Note that $K_0$ is finite or countably infinite, and $K_0(x_1)$ is finite or countably infinite (you can simply consider the case $\mathbb Q(x_1)$). This is because $$K_0(x_1)=K_0[x_1]\cup\bigcup_{i\geqslant 1,0\leqslant j< i} R_{ij},$$ where $R_{ij}$ is the set of rational fractions over $K_0$ with denominator of degree $i$ and numerator of degree $j$, while such $R_{ij}$ is also at most countably infinite. Induction shows that $K_0(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is at most countably infinite. Thus $$K_0(x_1,\cdots,x_n,\cdots)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_0(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$$ is countably infinite.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks!